# Как сделать плейлист через Owl Carousel

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

1) Как сделать автовоспроизведение активного видео в Owl Carousel (чтобы при загрузке страницы чразу начиналось видео)?

2) Как сделать так, чтобы при окончании одного видео, автоматически перелистывалось на следующее видео и также начиналось автовоспроизведение?

Answer (score 0):

Ответ нашел тут:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39854483/html5-video-in-owl-carousel-with-circular-autoplay-video-and-carosel

```js
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  items: 1,
  loop: true,
  dots: false,
  video: true,
  autoplay: true,
  onInitialized: function() {
    if ($(".owl-item.active video", this.$element).length) {
      $(".owl-item.active video", this.$element)[0].play();
      owl.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay')
      $(".owl-item.active video", this.$element).on('ended', function() {
        owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay')
      });
    }
  },
  onTranslated: function() {
    if ($(".owl-item.active video", this.$element).length) {
      $(".owl-item.active video", this.$element)[0].play();
      owl.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay')
      $(".owl-item.active video", this.$element).on('ended', function() {
        owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay')
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="http://owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<ul class="owl-carousel">
  <li>
    <video id="myVideo">
      <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg" alt="pic_mountain" style="height:250px" />
  </li>
</ul>
```